# LINQ Equal Operator Error in Query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to use LINQ in a VB.Net program to query a database.  This is my query statement:

```
Dim query = From p In db.Parts, s In db.Suppliers
            Join sName In db.Suppliers On s.Supplier_ID Equals p.Supplier_ID
            Select p.Part_Number, p.Part_Description, sName
```

The error I am getting is:

```
You must reference at least one range variable on both sides of the 'Equals' operator.
Range variable(s) 'p', 's' must appear on one side of the 'Equals' operator, and range variable(s) 'sName' must appear on the other.
```

What I am trying to do, is I have a Parts Table with a Column that has a Foreign Key referencing the Supplier_ID column in my Suppliers Table.  I am trying to make it so that I am grabbing the Supplier_Name field in my Supplier Table to display, instead of just the Supplier ID.

Everything I have tried looking up on Google shows me join syntax that is the same as mine, but obviously I am misunderstanding how this actually works.  So what is my problem?

I've tried changing things around because of the Error Message, but nothing seems to work, either the error message remains, or I just get more errors.

Comment: your `Equals` has no reference to `sName` which is the range variable for the RHS of the `join`. Not sure what the `s In db.Suppliers` is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @NetMage I just edited the OP with a description of what I am trying to accomplish, don't know why I neglected that at first >_<

Comment: Regardless of name, what do you think is the type of `sName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to microsoft docs ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/equals) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)), you have a couple issues here:

First, you are specifying both tables in the `From` clause, where you only have to specify the "left" part of your join.

```
Dim query = From p In db.Parts
```

Second, in the `Join` clause you are specifying an alias for `Suppliers` (sName) that you're not using.

```
Join s In db.Suppliers
```

Your final query should look like this:

```
Dim query = From p In db.Parts
        Join s In db.Suppliers On s.Supplier_ID Equals p.Supplier_ID
        Select p.Part_Number, p.Part_Description, sName
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I don't know how either of those MS Docs didn't come up with me searching for a solution over the better part of an hour, but whatever.